# Permission violation - getConfiguredNetworks not allowed for uid=10293, reason=java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10293 has no location permission

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working on app which works for sharing files whenever I connect to it through scanning it does not connect on target sdk version 29 and above but works fine on target sdk version 28 This happen only on android 10. Please help me. It has been working fine on all android 9 and later version but not working on android 10 version. What should i do please suggest me i am suffering from it. Please help i will be very thankful.

```
 This is my manifest file
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.Anand.ShareMe">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

    <application
        android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.base.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="@string/app_name"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TBShare"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/admob_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TBShare.NoActionBar">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.activity.ShareActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TBShare.NoActionBar.StaticStatusBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="genonbeta.intent.action.TBShare_SEND_TEXT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                <action android:name="genonbeta.intent.action.TBShare_SEND" />
                <action android:name="genonbeta.intent.action.TBShare_SEND_MULTIPLE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.activity.AddDevicesToTransferActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_addDevicesToTransfer"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TBShare.NoActionBar.StaticStatusBar" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.activity.FileExplorerActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_fileExplorer"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TBShare.NoActionBar.StaticStatusBar" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.activity.ConnectionManagerActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_connectDevices"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TBShare.NoActionBar.StaticStatusBar" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.activity.ContentSharingActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_send"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TBShare.NoActionBar.StaticStatusBar" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.activity.FilePickerActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_fileExplorer" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.activity.ViewTransferActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_transactionViewer"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TBShare.NoActionBar.StaticStatusBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />

                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.tshare" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.tshare" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.activity.ManageDevicesActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_manageDevices"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TBShare.NoActionBar"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.activity.SearchActivity"
            android:label="@string/butn_search" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.activity.TextEditorActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_textEditor" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.activity.ChangeStoragePathActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.genonbeta.intent.action.UPDATE_STORAGE_PATH" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.activity.BarcodeScannerActivity"
            android:label="@string/text_scanQrCode"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TBShare.BarcodeScannerActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.activity.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TBShare.NoActionBar" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.activity.WebShareActivity"
            android:label="Web Share"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TBShare.NoActionBar"/>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.receiver.NetworkStatusReceiver"
            android:process=":transfer">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.p2p.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.receiver.DialogEventReceiver"
            android:process=":transfer" />

        <service
            android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.service.CommunicationService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:label="@string/text_communicationService"
            android:process=":transfer" />

        <service
            android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.service.DeviceChooserService"
            android:label="@string/text_chooserTargetService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_CHOOSER_TARGET_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.chooser.ChooserTargetService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.service.DeviceScannerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="genonbeta.intent.action.SCAN_DEVICES" />
                <action android:name="genonbeta.intent.action.ADD_IP" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.service.WorkerService"
            android:label="@string/text_workerService" />

        <service
            android:name="com.Anand.ShareMe.service.CommunicationToggleTile"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/text_shareFiles"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE"
            android:process=":transfer">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

This is my ConnectionUtill code

```
package com.Anand.ShareMe.util;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.DhcpInfo;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.WorkerThread;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.Anand.ShareMe.base.AppConfig;
import com.Anand.ShareMe.adapter.NetworkDeviceListAdapter;
import com.genonbeta.android.framework.util.Interrupter;

import java.util.List;

public class ConnectionUtils
{
    public static final String TAG = ConnectionUtils.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context mContext;
    private WifiManager mWifiManager;
    private HotspotUtils mHotspotUtils;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager;

    ConnectionUtils(Context context) {
        mContext = context;

        mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getContext().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getContext().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mHotspotUtils = HotspotUtils.getInstance(getContext());
        mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    }

    public static ConnectionUtils getInstance(Context context) {
        return new ConnectionUtils(context);
    }

    public static String getCleanNetworkName(String networkName) {
        if (networkName == null)
            return "";

        return networkName.replace("\"", "");
    }

    public boolean canAccessLocation() {
        return hasLocationPermission(getContext()) && isLocationServiceEnabled();
    }

    public boolean canReadScanResults() {
        return getWifiManager().isWifiEnabled() && (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23 || canAccessLocation());
    }

    public boolean disableCurrentNetwork() {
        // TODO: Networks added by other applications will possibly reconnect even if we disconnect them
        // This is because we are only allowed to manipulate the connections that we added.
        // And if it is the case, then the return value of disableNetwork will be false.
        return isConnectedToAnyNetwork()
                && getWifiManager().disconnect()
                && getWifiManager().disableNetwork(getWifiManager().getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId());
    }

    @WorkerThread
    public String establishHotspotConnection(final Interrupter interrupter,
                                             final NetworkDeviceListAdapter.HotspotNetwork hotspotNetwork,
                                             final ConnectionCallback connectionCallback) {
        final int pingTimeout = 1000; // ms
        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String remoteAddress = null;
        boolean connectionToggled = false;
        boolean secondAttempt = false;
        boolean thirdAttempt = false;

        while (true) {
            int passedTime = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);

            // retry code will be here.
            if (passedTime >= 10000 && !secondAttempt) {
                secondAttempt = true;
                disableCurrentNetwork();
                connectionToggled = false;
            }

            if (passedTime >= 20000 && !thirdAttempt) {
                thirdAttempt = true;
                disableCurrentNetwork();
                connectionToggled = false;
            }

            if (!getWifiManager().isWifiEnabled()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "establishHotspotConnection(): Wifi is off. Making a request to turn it on");

                if (!getWifiManager().setWifiEnabled(true)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "establishHotspotConnection(): Wifi was off. The request has failed. Exiting.");
                    break;
                }
            } else if (!isConnectedToNetwork(hotspotNetwork) && !connectionToggled) {
                Log.d(TAG, "establishHotspotConnection(): Requested network toggle");
                toggleConnection(hotspotNetwork);

                connectionToggled = true;
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "establishHotspotConnection(): Waiting to connect to the server");
                final DhcpInfo routeInfo = getWifiManager().getDhcpInfo();
                //Log.w(TAG, String.format("establishHotspotConnection(): DHCP: %s", routeInfo));

                if (routeInfo != null && routeInfo.gateway != 0) {
                    final String testedRemoteAddress = NetworkUtils.convertInet4Address(routeInfo.gateway);

                    Log.d(TAG, String.format("establishHotspotConnection(): DhcpInfo: gateway: %s dns1: %s dns2: %s ipAddr: %s serverAddr: %s netMask: %s",
                            testedRemoteAddress,
                            NetworkUtils.convertInet4Address(routeInfo.dns1),
                            NetworkUtils.convertInet4Address(routeInfo.dns2),
                            NetworkUtils.convertInet4Address(routeInfo.ipAddress),
                            NetworkUtils.convertInet4Address(routeInfo.serverAddress),
                            NetworkUtils.convertInet4Address(routeInfo.netmask)));

                    Log.d(TAG, "establishHotspotConnection(): There is DHCP info provided waiting to reach the address " + testedRemoteAddress);

                    /*if (NetworkUtils.ping(testedRemoteAddress, pingTimeout)) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "establishHotspotConnection(): AP has been reached. Returning OK state.");
                        remoteAddress = testedRemoteAddress;
                        break;
                    } else
                        Log.d(TAG, "establishHotspotConnection(): Connection check ping failed");*/

                    if (UIConnectionUtils.isOSAbove(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
                            ? NetworkUtils.ping(testedRemoteAddress, pingTimeout)
                            : NetworkUtils.ping(testedRemoteAddress)) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "establishHotspotConnection(): AP has been reached. Returning OK state.");
                        remoteAddress = testedRemoteAddress;
                        break;
                    } else
                        Log.d(TAG, "establishHotspotConnection(): Connection check ping failed");

                } else
                    Log.d(TAG, "establishHotspotConnection(): No DHCP provided. Looping...");
            }

            if (connectionCallback.onTimePassed(1000, passedTime) || interrupter.interrupted()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "establishHotspotConnection(): Timed out or onTimePassed returned true. Exiting...");
                break;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }

        return remoteAddress;
    }

    public boolean hasLocationPermission(Context context) {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    public ConnectivityManager getConnectivityManager() {
        return mConnectivityManager;
    }

    public HotspotUtils getHotspotUtils() {
        return mHotspotUtils;
    }

    public LocationManager getLocationManager() {
        return mLocationManager;
    }

    public WifiManager getWifiManager() {
        return mWifiManager;
    }

    public boolean isConnectionSelfNetwork() {
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = getWifiManager().getConnectionInfo();

        return wifiInfo != null
                && getCleanNetworkName(wifiInfo.getSSID()).startsWith(AppConfig.PREFIX_ACCESS_POINT);
    }

    public boolean isConnectedToAnyNetwork() {
        NetworkInfo info = getConnectivityManager().getActiveNetworkInfo();

        return info != null
                && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI
                && info.isConnected();
    }

    public boolean isConnectedToNetwork(NetworkDeviceListAdapter.HotspotNetwork hotspotNetwork) {
        if (!isConnectedToAnyNetwork())
            return false;

        if (hotspotNetwork.BSSID != null)
            return hotspotNetwork.BSSID.equals(getWifiManager().getConnectionInfo().getBSSID());

        return hotspotNetwork.SSID.equals(getCleanNetworkName(getWifiManager().getConnectionInfo().getSSID()));
    }

    public boolean isLocationServiceEnabled() {
        return mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }

    public boolean isMobileDataActive() {
        return mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
    }

    public boolean toggleConnection(NetworkDeviceListAdapter.HotspotNetwork hotspotNetwork) {
        if (!isConnectedToNetwork(hotspotNetwork)) {
            if (isConnectedToAnyNetwork())
                disableCurrentNetwork();

            /*WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();
            config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.clear();
            config.allowedGroupCiphers.clear();
            config.allowedKeyManagement.clear();
            config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.clear();
            config.allowedProtocols.clear();*/

            WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();

            config.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", hotspotNetwork.SSID);

            switch (hotspotNetwork.keyManagement) {
                case 0: // OPEN
                    config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
                    break;
                case 1: // WEP64
                    config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
                    config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
                    config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
                    config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);

                    if (hotspotNetwork.password != null
                            && hotspotNetwork.password.matches("[0-9A-Fa-f]*")) {
                        config.wepKeys[0] = hotspotNetwork.password;
                    } else {
                        //fail("Please type hex pair for the password");
                    }
                    break;
                case 2: // WEP128
                    config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
                    config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
                    config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
                    config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);

                    if (hotspotNetwork.password != null
                            && hotspotNetwork.password.matches("[0-9A-Fa-f]*")) {
                        config.wepKeys[0] = hotspotNetwork.password;
                    } else {
                        //fail("Please type hex pair for the password");
                    }
                    break;
                case 3: // WPA_TKIP
                    config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
                    config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
                    config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
                    config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
                    config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);

                    if (hotspotNetwork.password != null
                            && hotspotNetwork.password.matches("[0-9A-Fa-f]{64}")) {
                        config.preSharedKey = hotspotNetwork.password;
                    } else {
                        config.preSharedKey = '"' + hotspotNetwork.password + '"';
                    }
                    break;
                case 4: // WPA2_AES
                    config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
                    config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
                    config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
                    config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
                    config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
                    config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);

                    if (hotspotNetwork.password != null
                            && hotspotNetwork.password.matches("[0-9A-Fa-f]{64}")) {
                        config.preSharedKey = hotspotNetwork.password;
                    } else {
                        config.preSharedKey = '"' + hotspotNetwork.password + '"';
                    }
                    break;
            }

            /*
            old wifi connectivity code works for below M
            int netId = getWifiManager().addNetwork(config);
            getWifiManager().disconnect();
            getWifiManager().enableNetwork(netId, true);
            return getWifiManager().reconnect();*/

            try {
                int netId = getWifiManager().addNetwork(config);

                if (/*Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= */UIConnectionUtils.isOSAbove(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)) {
                    List<WifiConfiguration> list = getWifiManager().getConfiguredNetworks();
                    for (WifiConfiguration hotspotWifi : list) {
                        if (hotspotWifi.SSID != null && hotspotWifi.SSID.equalsIgnoreCase(config.SSID)) {
                            getWifiManager().disconnect();
                            getWifiManager().enableNetwork(hotspotWifi.networkId, true);
                            return getWifiManager().reconnect();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    getWifiManager().disconnect();
                    getWifiManager().enableNetwork(netId, true);
                    return getWifiManager().reconnect();
                }
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                disableCurrentNetwork();
                return false;
            }
        }

        disableCurrentNetwork();

        return false;
    }

    public interface ConnectionCallback {
        boolean onTimePassed(int delimiter, long timePassed);
    }
}
```

[This is my stack strace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STO9o.png)

Answer (score -1):

It is not enough to specify the location permission in the manifest, you need to actually request it as well (like you do with `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_PHONE_STATE`).
That's why you see the `SecurityException: UID 10293 has no location permission` in your logs.

What you have stumbled upon is indeed [new in Android 10](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#configure-wifi).
Note though that this is simply an error being logged [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/modules/Wifi/service/java/com/android/server/wifi/WifiServiceImpl.java;l=2140?q=WifiServiceImpl).
Your app shouldn't crash, it will simply receive an empty list from `getConfiguredNetworks` (and print those logs).

However, once you successfully request the permissions, you will probably end up being caught by [this next check](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/modules/Wifi/service/java/com/android/server/wifi/WifiServiceImpl.java;l=2152?q=WifiServiceImpl) (unless your app is a carrier app).
Thus you might need to reconsider if you want to target API 29 (not realistic in the long run) or consider other solutions to implement your feature.

Comment: I am new in android studio can you tell me how can i do this.

Comment: Well, what  is it you are trying to achieve?

If you simply want the error in the logs to go away, you could actively request the location permission (like you do for the other permissions in `checkPermission()`.

Comment: If you desire more help, you need to [ask better questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide better details. E.g. describe what exactly you are trying to achieve.
Give a minimum reproducible example, rather than a dump of code. In particular, the code you posted (`MainActivity`) doesn't even contain the part responsible for your error.
From your [log image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) I would guess `ConnectionUtils` is what we need to see, but alas, you didn't post it.

Comment: Now I have posted ConnectionUtill code please look into it and help me.